# Using :target #id and classes to show/hide navigation without JS

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I am struggling to make a show/hide button within my navigation to work. My goal is do this purely with CSS. It is supposed to activate when the browser screen is too small to display all the navigation items. I am successful in hiding the items I do not want seen at certain screen widths, however I cannot seem to get the link which activates the :target to display them when clicked.

Here is the css

```
nav {width:100%; min-width:287px;}
nav ul {padding:0;}
nav li {
   list-style: none;
   width:26%;
   min-width:67px;
   display:block;
   line-height: 2.5em;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
   background-color:#333;
   box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px #333;
   text-align:center;}

nav li a {color:#fff; text-decoration:none; height:100%; font-size:1em; display:block; white-space:nowrap;}

nav li:hover {background-color:#BA7007;}
nav li a:hover {color:#FFF;}
nav li a:visited {color:#FFF; background-color:#333;}

.prio-alpha {}
.prio-gamma, 
.prio-beta, 
.show-nav-less {display: none;}

#prio:target + .prio-beta, 
#prio:target + .prio-gamma, 
#prio:target + .show-nav-less {display: block; }

#prio:target + .show-nav-more { display: none; }
.show-nav-more {width:20%;}

@media screen and (min-width: 41em) {
    nav li {width:20%;}
    nav li a {font-size:1.4em;}
    .prio-beta {    display: block; }
    #prio:target + .prio-gamma, #prio:target + .show-nav-less {display: block;} 
    #prio:target + .show-nav-more { display: none; }}

@media screen and (min-width: 65em) {
    nav li {width:16.5%;}
    .prio-gamma {    display: block; }

    .show-nav-more, 
    #prio:target + .show-nav-less { display: none; } }
```

and html:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="prio-beta"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="prio-alpha"><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
    <li class="prio-alpha"><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
    <li class="prio-gamma"><a href="Space_Flies.html">Space Flies</a></li>
    <li class="prio-gamma"><a href="Aging_PPG.html">Aging PPG Project</a></li>
    <li class="prio-alpha"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="show-nav-more"><a href="#prio">+ more</a></li>
    <li class="show-nav-less"><a href="#">- less</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to switch up the order, placing the class in front of the :target and even removing #prior and just using .class:target to no apparent difference in the function of the code when live.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you just want it so that you don't need JS for a submenu to open on click?

Here's a very quick/dirty version, it should get the idea across and hopefully you can edit it for your needs

### Quick and Dirty

```css
#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  padding: 3px;
}
#nav #show_more {
  display: none;
}
#nav li:target {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
  <li>Page 4</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#show_more">More</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li id="show_more">
        There is more stuff here, woo.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

### One that uses Hovers

This should give a bit more responsiveness when hovering over a menu item. I'm not sure what you are going for, but hopefully one of these helps.

```css
 #nav,
 #nav > li {
   list-style-type: none;
   position: relative;
 }
 #nav li {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-sizing: padding-box;
   padding: 3px;
 }
 #nav li > ul {
   display: none;
 }
 #nav li:hover >ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: block;
 }
 #nav li:hover >ul li {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
  <li>Page 4</li>
  <li>
    More
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 4</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 5</li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Sadly, neither of these options will succeed in accomplishing what I am trying to do. Perhaps if you visit my site (bodmerlab.org) you can better see what I mean. My goal is not to add more menu items. My goal is when the screen width is reduced (either in the browser or on a smaller device), only prior-alpha class items are visible with the option to "show more". Depending on the screen width, .prior-beta and .prior-gamma will display. When all classes display the "more" or "less" option is removed. Does that make more sense?

Comment: So you're trying to use media queries to collapse the menu and use nothing but CSS to expand those items when the "more" link is clicked?

Comment: Well, I'm not going to pretend that I totally understand how to use media queries for smaller screens, but I think [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) would be a good start, and you could come back and ask a different question when you get to a place that you need more help. If you want to see an example of Bootstrap collapse, The most direct one I found was [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp).
Sorry I can't help more - CSS things like this aren't my forte.